# Bigquery: Loops – inner and outer

Tags: loops, google-bigquery

I'm trying run loop within loop in Bigquery:

```
DECLARE index_barrier INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE barrier_ranges DEFAULT (select generate_array(2,4));
DECLARE index_freq INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE freq_run string;
DECLARE freq_range ARRAY<STRING>;
SET freq_range = ['Daily','Bi-daily'];


LOOP
  IF index_freq = array_length(freq_range) THEN BREAK; END IF;
  LOOP
    IF index_barrier = array_length(barrier_ranges) THEN BREAK; END IF;
    --DECLARE freq_run string DEFAULT freq_range[OFFSET(index_freq)];
    SET freq_run = freq_range[OFFSET(index_freq)];
    BEGIN
      DECLARE barrier_run INT64 DEFAULT barrier_ranges[OFFSET(index_barrier)];
      select freq_run as freq,
             index_freq as index_freq,
             barrier_run as barrier
      ;
      SET index_barrier = index_barrier + 1;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  SET index_freq = index_freq + 1;
END LOOP;
```

But the issue is that it runs only on the first value of outer loop 'Daily'.
I guess the problem with IF statement in inner loop with the BREAK.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just to add `SET index_barrier = 0;` after `SET index_freq = index_freq + 1`